# Dangling pointer and segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dangling-pointer

Here is an example code:

```
class IntWrapper
{
public:
   IntWrapper(int value_ = 0): value(value_) {}

   int getNumber()
   {
      return value;
   }

   void setNumber(int value_)
   {
      value = value_;
   }
private:
   int value;
};

class T
{
public:
   T(){}

   void test()
   {
      std::cout << ptr->getNumber() << std::endl;
      ptr->setNumber(10);
      std::cout << ptr->getNumber() << std::endl;
   }

private:
   IntWrapper *ptr;
};


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   T t;
   t.test(); // may cause segmentation fault

   return 0;
}
```

ptr that's a dangling pointer. When I run that program it prints:

```
1
10
```

but it also may cause a segmentation fault (even if only a function which read a memory - getNumber is called).

1. There is no segmentation fault when a memory location pointed by ptr is not allocated by other object(program), right ? How to explain that ?

Comment: This is called "undefined behavior". Basically, anything can happen - literally. I've seen cases of it which caused values to be treated as both true and false at the same time.

Comment: By the way, the code you show doesn't sport a *dangling* pointer - in the commons sense of the term. It is usually called *uninitialized* pointer. Dangling pointer is something which was valid sometime ago, but not any more.

Comment: In C++ there are few reasons to use a pointer at all.

Comment: In C++ there are few reasons to use a *raw* pointer at all. Pointers to allocated memory should be wrapped in resource management classes and code outside of those classes should rarely need raw pointers to allocated memory. Pointers to non-heap memory are still sometimes useful, and of course somebody needs to write the resource management classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ptr is never initialized it may point to anything - code, data, stack, unmapped memory, memory that is mapped but not in an in-use range. That is, the address in the ptr member variable could contain random leftover data, special values generated by the compiler or heap implementation, or ???

Reasoning about why you do or do not get a segmentation fault in these circumstances is not particularly useful or meaningful in most cases. Just don't do that. It's "undefined behavior" and can cause arbitrarily unpredictable things to happen.

Comment: What's often overlooked: Undefined behavior doesn't just apply to the single statement that causes it, but to the program as a whole. If you trigger UB you are left without a single guarantee.

Comment: BTW, understanding what actually happens in these circumstances can be useful when investigating crashes, but the advice of "don't do that" still applies. And, any understanding of what happens will necessarily include "it depends" on the compiler, compiler settings, OS, surrounding code, and many other factors. The results will often vary from run to run.